# How can I include guidance text in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

We use several Word documents as templates and currently include 'guidance' text for the reader - in the form of grey, italic text - to provide guidance to the person completing the document.

[image: Example]

Note how the grey+italic text is used to provide both guidance and example content

Problems with this approach include:

- People forgetting to delete all of this template/boilerplate text
- People using the italic+grey formatting when inputting *real* information because they don't change the style

We've considered including Reviewing comments as an alternative but this can be a pain and suffers from the first problem above.

I'm not sure a simple, elegant solution exists here but if there's something obvious I'm missing I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: What is done with the completed document, is it printed?

Comment: Nope - sent to the customer as a .docx (and I can't rely on people removing comments).

Comment: "I can't rely on people removing comments" is all very well, but there are so many things that people can put in a Word document that could reach the customer that it's difficult to imagine not having a "publish" process where (for example), someone other than the creator of the document checks the content, perhaps some standard procedures are applied, and so on. i.e. what can you rely on?

Comment: True, but it still seems sensible to try to minimise the number of things that might get left in there.

Answer (score 2):

You could improve the experience by putting the help text into [content controls](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html). Each controls can include default text which you would set to the help text that you want and can be set so the control (and the help text along with it) is removed when the user starts typing into it.

Using content controls should also remove the issue of the writer using incorrect formatting for real text as the default text shares a completely different style which isn't inherited when the user begins writing in the control.

When it comes to removing all help text in places where the writer may not be required to enter any information, you may need to run a macro to remove any left over content controls, however keep in mind, you would be required to do this for your original solution anyway to make sure all text is removed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that this solves your issue but this is how I do it.
the text that I want as an instruction and should not be shown when the doc is finished I do selecting that text and formatting it as hidden then this text will only show when the the "show/hidden" button is selected to show.
[text formatting option to hide selected text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO3Ie.png)  and the [show/hide button icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fni71.png)